# Creating another layout template for a Site made with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, layout, routes

I'm trying to create two separate layout templates in ruby because everything is defaulting to the application.html.er layout, but I can't seem to get it right. Ive tried about 5 solutions on here and none of them seem to work for my code. Please someone help?


**app/controllers/pages_controller.rb :**

`

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
        layout :homeLayout_layout
    end
end
```

`

**views/layouts/homeLayout.html.erb:**

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Checklance</title>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css", "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js", "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>


  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
      <div class="container" id="body">
        <a id="nav" class="navbar-brand" href="/projects">
            <img src="http://i1051.photobucket.com/albums/s423/Kira-Banks/check-2.png" id="logo">
            Checklance
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="homeContainer">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>

    <footer id="footer">Copyright 2014 Kira Banks</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

`

**views/pages/home.html.erb :**

`

```
<h1 id="homeTitle">Welcome!</h1>
```

`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file names should all be snake_case in Rails. Change `views/layouts/homeLayout.html.erb` to `views/layouts/home_layout.html.erb` and your controller should look like:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
   render layout: "home_layout"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can mention the newly created layout top of the controller. So, that will be effective in all action's of the respective controller and your controller should look like:

class PagesController < ApplicationController

layout: "home_layout"

def home

end

end